# I am confused. What is window.scrollY, and how is it different from something like String.concat?

Tags: javascript

I want to clarify that I know what each of them do. I'm just having trouble understanding the organization of such elements. So I know that in things like `String.concat`, concat is a prototype of `String`.  However, what would `Window.scrollY` be? I want to say that scrollY is a prototype of Window but I have a gut feeling that is not the case. Also, when I go to a page like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), there is a long list of APIs. Is window an API? in that case, is String an API as well?

Comment: Keep your questions to specific technical issues only.  New users who ask poor questions get auto-banned.

Comment: _"`concat` is a prototype of `String`."_ - No it isn't, it's a method of the `String` prototype and as such is available to all `String` instances. `scrollY` is simply a property of the `window` object. (Note that `window` has a lowercase `w`.) It may help you to read [the MDN article "Working with objects"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1):

> So I know that in things like String.concat, concat is a prototype of String.

You seem a bit confused. There is no `String.concat`, though there is `String.prototype.concat` which is inherited by instances of *String*. It would be called a [*Property of the String Prototype Object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4) or an [*inherited property of a string instance*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5).

> However, what would Window.scrollY be?

I suspect you mean `window.scrollY`, note the lower case *w*. It is a property of a [*Window object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY). Since it will likely be different for different windows, it is a property of the object itself, an "own property", and not inherited.

Window objects are host objects and therefore must comply with certain parts of ECMAScript but are generally free to do whatever they want, as long as they don’t contradict the parts of the standard that apply to them. For example, Host objects don’t have to implement any kind of inheritance and can return strange values for [*typeof*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3):

> Object (host and does not implement [[Call]])
>   Implementation-defined except may not be "undefined", "boolean", "number", or "string".

The [*Global object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) doesn’t inherit from anything, it just “is”. There is no *Global* constructor, you can’t instatiate a new *global* object using `new Global()` and there is no `Global.prototype`.

However, you can create a new Window object using `window.open()` so there is a Window constructor and most browsers do implement prototype inheritance. And since *window* is a synonym for the global object, it gets quite messy. For example, in some browsers:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === Object.getPrototypeOf(window) // true
```

which leads to the idea that there **is** a `Global.protoype`, which inherits from the built–in Object constructor:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) == Object.prototype // true
```

and also:

```
// Note that in global code, this references the global object
alert(typeof this.foo); // undefined

Window.prototype.foo = function(){alert('I am foo')};

alert(typeof this.foo); // function

this.foo(); // I am foo

var w = window.open(); // Opens a new window
w.foo();               // TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'w.foo()')
```

However that is likely peculiar to some browsers and should not be relied upon to implement any kind of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, objects have properties and methods. Properties are objects or values, while methods are exclusively functions. The nomenclature is derived from other Object oriented programming languages, but in JS, the actuality is that methods and properties are the same thing because of loose typing.

Sometimes methods are added to methods are added to objects using the `prototype` property that is present on every object. The `prototype` property is only really useful if you plan on replicating the object using the `new` keyword (creating instances of a class). Otherwise for one-off objects, you can assign properties and methods directly on the object without using prototype.

Also worth noting that everything in javascript is an object. Functions are objects, strings are objects, arrays are objects, etc..

Here's some further study for you http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/09/09/learning-javascript/